# How to disable shm and wal options for Core Data on SwiftUI 2?

Tags: swift, core-data

When we create a new SwiftUI2 project using Xcode, it creates this class for the core data initialization.

```
class PersistenceController {
  static let shared = PersistenceController()
  
  let container: NSPersistentContainer
  
  init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
  
    container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyApp")

    if inMemory {
      container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
    }
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
      if let error = error as NSError? {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        
        /*
         Typical reasons for an error here include:
         * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
         * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
         * The device is out of space.
         * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
         Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
         */
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
      }
    })
  }
  var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
    return container.viewContext
  }
}
```

I want to disable `shm` and `wal` options of core data.

I would need to do something like

```
let persistentStoreCoordinator = container.persistentStoreCoordinator
let options = [NSSQLitePragmasOption: ["journal_mode": "DELETE"]]
let persistenceStore = persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.first
persistenceStore?.options = options
```

but I don't see how because the persistenceStore there is already created and will not let me to set its read-only options.

How do I do that?

Comment: You should read [this article](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/write-ahead-logging-wal/), I think it might answer your question.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @TomHarrington. I need to have it commit the data to the sqlite file immediately because I am developing an app that will allow the user to backup the database and it is not good to zip 3 files with uncommited changes for backup.

Comment: @Ronnie There's a better way to back up Core Data than by copying files. https://atomicbird.com/blog/core-data-back-up-store/

Comment: @TomHarrington. What I am developing is the iOS version of an android app. The android version uses a server API to send the database. Unfortunately I need to do it like this. It just accepts sqlite files.

Comment: You have my sympathy, and I hope you get a better server team someday.

Comment: @TomHarrington... and you have to see how disorganized they are. I am building this app by instruments, without ever seeing land... 

Answer (score 0):

NSPersistentContainer has a property persistentStoreDescriptions that you can set before calling loadPersistentStores(completionHandler:)  The persistentStoreDescriptors object has a setValue(_:forPragmaNamed:)